# One to One relationship

Tags: database

I have two tables (Reservation) and (Invoice).

Reservation incurs one invoice, an invoice is incurred by one reservation, the relationship is 1..1.

The question is, how should i use foreign keys here, do i sent the reservation_no(PK) to invoice entity or invoice_no to reservation entity

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your business rules, do you NEED invoice data when looking at a reservation? Or do you NEED reservation data when looking at an invoice? If it were me, I would probably stick the reservation_id within the invoice table.

Comment: Agree with @Mike. Sounds like reservation comes first.

Comment: Hiya business rule state; Once the holiday reservation is booked, the customer is invoiced for the holiday, so i guess i am going to stick the reservation_no in the invoice instead.

Comment: Wouldn't the user flow be something like: User selects days -> User books reservation -> User pays for reservation? If so, reservation would always be present, whereas invoice would only be present if the user actually completed the billing cycle.